# App working in emulator but crashes on the phone

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter

Succesfully made an app but gives me errors when i run it on the phone

works fine on the emulator which is present in android studio

Main activity:

```
private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "smth";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "smth";
private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton =(TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);

    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>()

                            {
                                @Override
                                public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                                    TwitterSession session= result.data;
                                    String user=session.getUserName();
                                    Intent tl=new Intent(MainActivity.this, TweetListActivity.class);
                                    Bundle b= new Bundle();
                                    b.putString("username",user);
                                    tl.putExtras(b);
                                    startActivity(tl);
                                }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                                Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
                            }
                        }

);
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
statusesService.show(524971209851543553L, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {

    }

    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        //Do something on failure


     }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

TweetList activity:

```
String user;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timeline);
    Intent tl=getIntent();
    Bundle b =tl.getExtras();

    if(null != b){
        user = b.getString("username");
    }
    final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
            .screenName(user)
            .build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
            .setTimeline(userTimeline)
            .build();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

activity main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rohil.aurus.MainActivity">


    <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
        android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

tweet_list.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="empty"/>

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

works fine on the emulator but crashes on the phone
Galaxy S4- 1920x1080p
Android 5.1.1
made the app for minimum sdk 21

Logcat:

```
 D/AndroidRuntime(29639): Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime(29639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29639): Process: com.rohil.aurus, PID: 29639
E/AndroidRuntime(29639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rohil.aurus/com.rohil.aurus.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must have valid session. Did you authenticate with Twitter?
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must have valid session. Did you authenticate with Twitter?
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.getApiClient(TwitterCore.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at com.rohil.aurus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
E/AndroidRuntime(29639):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager( 3214):   Force finishing activity 1 com.rohil.aurus/
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byu333mD4mcSYi01X2N1Sjg3X1k/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Please post your log cat messages which are generated during running application on the mobile so that anyone can help you.Also post your manifest file.

Comment: First, add please full logcat with error. Second, are  you sure you run it on emulator, maybe you just looked at Layout Editor, which fact is built into android studio - sorry I needed to eask

Comment: I ran full emulator, logged into twitter, and even went to the next activity

Comment: Post your logcat **in the question**. An ephemeral link does not a good question make.

Comment: Added my Logcat in the question, thanks

Comment: `Must have valid session. Did you authenticate with Twitter?` well did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API requires authentication. With your emulator you probably did this at some point during development. Since the authentication key persists, you probably made changes to surpass this step and now, when you install on a fresh device, the authentication has not occurred and therefore you get this error.

If you check your code, or review Twitter's documentation, you will find where you by-pass this step at this point. Twitter's Oauth docs are here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth